# Unity: animation event does not change animated object`s transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, events

I want an enemy to look at the player when he shoots him, I call this function from an animation event:

```
    public void ShootPlayer
    {
        thisTr.LookAt(playerTr);
        thisTr.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, thisTr.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        GameObject newArrow = Instantiate(straightFlightArrow, shootPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        em.canMove = true;
    }
```

It does get called, but model`s rotation does not change. The weird thing is, if I invoke thisTr.LookAt(playerTr) in Start(), the model will rotate accordingly during the shoot animation. Also, if I rotate the model from another script the same way before the shoot animation starts it will work as well.

So for some reason trying to rotate the model specifically from the animation event does not work for me. I have tried checking constraints on and off, applied and disabled root motion, but there is no effect. I am sure that there is some obvious mistake that I make, but I just can`t figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Properties that are being animated (i.e. inhibited by the animation engine) cannot be set from code. There's a workaround for it, but it's ugly - you need to do your update in LateUpdate() (so it's after the animation engine does it's transformations) and you have to keep track of the updated value, overwriting it each and every frame (because otherwise the engine will overwrite your next frame with what it had calculated).

Other workarounds involve wrapping GameObjects in empty GameObjects, i.e. my animator animated an object's position, which I wanted to change in code as well, so my structure was:

```
animatedContainer
    |- actualObjectAlsoAnimatedFromCode
```

As far as I know this also applies to properties which are inhibited at some point, but not necessarily changed during current animation (and I think this is the issue your case is facing).

Comment: Thanks, I`ve made a dirty workaround by calling Invoke() in that method, for some reason object`s rotation values do change and can be checked with Debug.Log() before and after LookAt(), but model`s rotation in the scene does not, I checked frame by frame in editor.

Comment: Your code will update the rotation correctly, but the animation engine is going to overwrite it anyway, that's why Debug.Log shows the correct info, but scene does not. For comparison and to see the issue, try setting the rotation to a constant value in LateUpdate() - you'll see that this is where you want to overwrite the values. [You can see here, that animator sets the values after Update() but before LateUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html?_ga=2.107705995.887769406.1572262611-2071001063.1571398828)